# Prevent asp:ImageButton Default inline Style

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton

Unfortunately the asp:ImageButton control renders an inline style attribute of "border-width:0px;" This is frustrating for a variety of reasons. In the past I have worked around the problem by creating my own custom image button control which doesn't render the inline style attribute. I am looking for a more elegant solution to the problem. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Here is**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493800/how-to-build-imagebutton-control-adapter-or-more-general-how-to-build-a-simple) a very simple [ControlAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.adapters.controladapter.aspx) which demonstrates adding the attribute when desired, and leaving it off entirely when not.

Comment: Somehow I missed that question and answer when I did cursory searches. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! The Adapter is much cleaner than writing my own control.