# Why does ASP.Net add a "border" attribute to asp:Image

Tags: asp.net, validation, xhtml

So I have an asp.net image tag:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/img.jpg" width="350px" height="250px" AlternateText="My Image" />
```

but it's outputting this:

```
<img src="Images/img.jpg" height="250" width="350" border="0" />
```

...the XHTML validator reckons that the "border" element shouldn't be there...but it's ASP.Net that's adding it.

I'm sure this question has been asked many times before, but why does asp.net think it needs to add it, especially because it's invalid??

How can this be avoided so that it does validate?

Answer (score 2):

It's the way that the ASP.NET image web control works. Unfortunately, many of the built in ASP.NET web controls are not standards complaint and will cause a page to not validate. The [CSS Friendly Control Adapters](http://cssfriendly.codeplex.com/) are a valiant attempt to "fix" the occasionally invalid and less than semantic HTML generated by the built in web controls.

Your particular issue can be avoided by following the advice in the answer to [How to build ImageButton Control Adapter.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493800/how-to-build-imagebutton-control-adapter-or-more-general-how-to-build-a-simple/509804#509804)

Comment: Yes, well that's very easy to say, but can it be avoided.  At the moment my page doesn't validate because of it...

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with Dan, the img tag will render with a style instead of border="0", but with the rather little research i did, the border=0 only disappears when you apply a style to the control with img {border: none} either in an external stylesheet or on the same page, how the magic happens was beyond the scope of my research. However, i have noticed that the validator still gets a border=0 in the markup, which means that asp.net renders differently depending on the type of browser (or browser agent i think), and to solve this i had to force asp to always render 'clean' code, as illustrated here

http://blog.hmobius.com/post/2010/03/03/ASPNET-Part-9-Rendering-Cleaner-HTML.aspx

so in my case, i added to the web.config file

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID">
```

also another point, i am using the html5 doctype, so make sure that the doctype of your page is not the problem.

and my page validates.

Answer (score 1):

By default, if an `<img>` element appears within an `<a>` element, the `<img>` gets an ugly blue border to signify that it's a link.

`border="0"` is an old-school (but simple, reliable and stand-alone) way to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't always invalid. In the old days, we all added the border="0" to avoid the default blue border when the image was linked. Unfortunately, the ASP.NET team hasn't found it worth while to update the Image control along with the web standards.

Btw, the border attribute is far from the only noncompliant HTML that ASP.NET emits.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ASP.NET 1.1? Because in 2.0 and above the image tag renders as:

```
    <img src="/Images/img.jpg" alt="My Image" 
style="height:250px;width:350px;border-width:0px;" />
```

I've just tested this and the above is what I get (using Opera 10) with a doctype of XHTML 1.0 Transitional. So I'm not sure why you are getting invalid HTML, unless ASP.NET is somehow [detecting your browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk9az15a.aspx) as "down level".

- What browser are you using?
- What version of .net?
- What doctype do you have?

Comment: if you change your browsers user agent string to, for example, google bots string agent, you for sure will get the border="0" attribute on your rendering. For common debugging/browsing will not. But won't pass the html validation ass the validation is done using a custom user agent.

Answer (score 0):

`border="0"` was necessary for Netscape 4, which didn't support the usual CSS way of doing it properly. Of course not much in ASP.NET will actually work with Netscape 4, so this attempt at backwards compatibility is pretty pointless.

Incidentally, as well as the ASP.NET controls' markup being poor, it actually still does browser-sniffing in this day and age: it will omit the related but even more invalid ‘border="0"’ on image buttons for browsers it thinks are ‘good’: a selection of whitelisted browsers that does not include the HTML validator.

Browser-sniffing is a Wrong Thing and most of us stopped doing years ago, but ASP.NET still does it by default, unless you use an upstream [clientTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clienttarget.aspx) in your page declaration to make it stop. Ugly stuff, MS.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to mess up with the web config (As I did), because targeting another framework on rendering will affect all your project controls rendering, and for huge projects this is not an option, you can always use this "on-page" solution by inserting this line at the end of your form before body closing tag(requires jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">$('#yourImageId').removeAttr("border");</script>
```

Using this will not pass HTML validation, the best way I've founded for validating the form is no using the asp control but the regular img tag, making it accessible from code behind with the runat="server" property:

```
<img ID="myImage" src="Images/img.jpg" height="250" width="350" runat="server"/>
```

This solution will do pass the HTML validation and you will be able to modify image attributes from code behind.